# Viewcontroller does not have a member named

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Within my code my variables are not being recognized multiple times throughout my code,

```
let now = NSDate()
let nowData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(now)
var error : NSError?
```

This error occurs twice throughout my code, the first occurrence is on the second line, highlighting the word now,  and the error reads  Viewcontroller.type does not have a member named now. Secondly inside of one of my IBActions when I send the time, nowData is highlighted and the error message is "Viewcontroller does not have a member named nowData".  I am unsure as to why these variables are simply not being recognized throughout my code although they are declared right in plain sight.  Perhaps this is an xcode error?

```
    self.session.sendData(nowData, toPeers:   self.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Unreliable, error: &error)
```

Comment: Are these variables declared at the top level of your class (as opposed to being in a constructor call or what have you?) it's likely that inline initializations of class members can't depend on other class members.

Comment: Yes they are declared in the top level of my class, thanks, that fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables with inline initializations can't depend on other instance members. If your instance variables depend on each other at initialization, initialize them in init instead of inline.

```
class MyClass
{
    let first: FirstType
    let second: SecondType

    init() {
        first = getFirst()
        second = getSecondWithFirst(first)
    }
}
```